# python is ignoring time.sleep(1)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Hi I am trying to run a small python program to control the gpio headers on the raspberry pi and I want it to wait 1 second before turning on each led but instead of sleeping in between each led it waits and sleeps at the end instead (it sleeps for the total 3 seconds which is all the seconds added up).Here is the code I am using

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(True)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)

print"Lights"
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)

GPIO.output(23,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)

GPIO.output(24,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: So just to clarify, it prints ```Lights```, does all the ```GPIO.output()``` lines correctly, and _then_ sleeps for three seconds?

Comment: Yes it turns on all the leds then sleeps for 3 seconds

Comment: Same question as @wnnmaw, also what happens if you put additional print statements after each output.

Comment: I added a print statement after each output and it just ran them at the end but with a 1 second delay in between

Answer (score 5):

It appears that

```
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
```

is turning on your LED's, not

```
GPIO.output(24,GPIO.HIGH)
```

Make sure you put your print statements between the `GPIO.OUT` statements like so:

```
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
time.sleep(1)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)
time.sleep(1)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
```

Comment: Updated my answer for clarification.

Comment: GPIO.OUT can not turn the leds on it can only set them up as an output GPIO.HIGH and GPIO.LOW turn the leds off and on

Comment: I added in the print statements after setting each gpio to out and now it turns the leds on, prints the statements i just added all at once, prints the statements after each GPIO.HIGH with a one second delay then turns the leds off

Comment: Indeed, this is about the default level that the setup command outputs. I have also found that the default level is the last level you set. So, if the last time you used "GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)", you then asserted it low, and you then changed pin 24 to an input, the next time you use "GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)", it will start low be default.

Answer (score 2):

The initial delay may just be setup time.

Based on http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/ try

```
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
```

To set them initially off.

i.e.

```
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: where are you saying I should add it at?

Comment: @zcarp1020 Look at Martin Konecny's answer

Comment: @zcarp1020 replace your setup calls with the ones I added above. I am just set an initial value for each of the channels. Martin's answer should also work.

Comment: okay I did that and it worked but I am still a bit unsure of why my original code didnt work because I have been using it without problems for a while now.

Comment: @zcarp1020 I am unsure but do the GPIO pins "remember" their last state? Could you have inverted any connection that would have caused this to happen?

Comment: The gpio connections can remember there last state but GPIO.cleanup() prevents them from doing so.

Comment: Not sure then, perhaps the script crashed or was terminated one time before cleanup was able to execute? Initializing the outputs to a known value is probably not the worst practice though to avoid issues like this.